# Missing permissions required by CameraManager.openCamera: android.permission.CAMERA

Tags: android

I'm trying to open the camera, but the error closes the application. Yesterday the code worked, for some reason now it does not work on the physical phone

private void connectCamera() {

```
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }

        int permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
            //java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service
        }

        cameraManager.openCamera("0", mCameraDeviceStateCallback,null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}
```

[java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3LpN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

On some phones, `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission` does not work, so I wrote this, you can try.

https://github.com/dengyuhan/CameraPermissionCompat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)` is non-blocking, so what actually happens is your app requests permission but before the user could grant it (or even the dialog could be displayed), the `cameraManager.openCamera(...)` line gets executed, which obviously throws an exception if the permission wasn't granted beforehand. This means that you have to branch your operations here:

- if you have the permission granted, execute `cameraManager.openCamera(...)`
- if you *don't* have the permission granted, call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)` and wait for the results in `onRequestPermissionsResult(...)`

When you have the results (and the permission was granted), you can open the camera:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] results) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_ALL: 
            if (results.length > 0 && results[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission granted
                cameraManager.openCamera("0", mCameraDeviceStateCallback,null);
            } else {
                // permission denied
            }

            return;
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to put this permission in your manifest file too if your `minSdkVersion` is less than 23.

Check out [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for more details.